# Determine the user-selected item in a JComboBox in Java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

How can I determine the selected item by the user in a `JComboBox`?

I tried this code:

```
double combofir = Integer.parseInt(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    // in this line how can I set the item that I want to know?

 double x = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
 double combosec = Integer.parseInt(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
 if (combofir == combosec) {
     double a = 72.873;
     double result = x*a;
     jTextField2.setText(""+result);

 }
```

Comment: Is this code block inside a listener callback method?

Comment: Also why are you using `Integer.parseInt` to get a `double`? All the primitive object wrappers have their own `parse` method, i.e. `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: @peeskillet not, to put Double to model